# HTMLTestRunner ImportError

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, test-runner

I m new to selenium + python.

I am facing a problem when I include htmltestrunner to generate a report. I'm using Python3.4.

Below is my code, please let me know if I'm doing something different than I am supposed to.

```
class TestOfReport(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.driver=webdriver.Firefox()
    self.base_url="https://www.google.co.in/"
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    self.verificationErrors = []
    self.accept_next_alert = True

def test_TestOfReport(self):
    driver=self.driver
    driver.get(self.base_url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.find_element_by_id("sb_ifc0").send_keys("selenium webdriver")
    driver.find_element_by_name("btnK").click()
    self.assertIn("Google",driver.title)

def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()
    self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
HTMLTestRunner.main()
```

error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensio
ns\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.1\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 1
06, in exec_file
    exec_code(code, file, global_variables)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensio
ns\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.1\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 8
2, in exec_code
    exec(code_obj, global_variables)
  File "c:\users\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\TestOfR
eport\TestOfReport\TestOfReport.py", line 10, in <module>
    import HTMLTestRunner
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\HTMLTestRunner.py", line 94, in <module>
    import StringIO
ImportError: No module named 'StringIO'
```

Answer (score 2):

The `StringIO` and `cStringIO` modules have been removed from Python-3.x. Instead, import the `io` module and use `io.StringIO`. [Doc link](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html).

```
from io import StringIO
```